# How to calculate between the elements of 3 lists?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 columns, 3 sets of numbers. I want to compare the sum between the numbers to a value I know. Was concatenate while trying to sum. So I put the known value into a variable and tried to subtract those values from zero. But stops on the way.
number sets [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MFYuKd8P0bzkpUa0iufmuQ4uK9t65bHuRnxtaGMvaTI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function matchCal() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var listA = ss.getRange("J1:J13").getValues();
  var listC = ss.getRange("L1:L13").getValues();
  var listE = ss.getRange("E1:E151").getValues();
  var myV = 5300; //my value

  for(var i=0; i<listA.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<listC.length; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<listE.length; k++){            
         if((myV -listA[i]-listC[j])==0 ){
           ss.getRange(1,1,i,1).setBackground(yellow);
           Logger.log("index A "+i);
           Logger.log(listA[i]);
           ss.getRange(1,3,j,1).setBackground(yellow);
            Logger.log("index C"+j);
           Logger.log(listC[j]);
           ss.getRange(1,3,k,1).setBackground(yellow);
            Logger.log("index C"+k);
           Logger.log(listE[j]);    
         }Logger.log("A" +i + " C"+j + " E"+k);            
        }            
      }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Please begin debuggin and share the details

Comment: you shared a file, but it does not give any access

Comment: @MattKing Try now.

Comment: I dont understand what you say about concatenating. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Aerials see this example. `listA= 1,2,3,4,5`   `listC= 12,13,14,15,16` `listD= 22, 23,24,25,26`   First I tried to find the sum of these elements at 5300 values. But then the answer came  `11222, 11223, 11224,....` Concatenate here only when sum values. Subtraction and multiplication did not have such a problem. So I reduced the element values from 5300. Then what I wanted happened. But the for Loop stops after the following position. `[A12] [C12] [E150]` . Stopping here is the problem I have. I apologize for my poor English.

Comment: Everyone download and play this gif file. Then I hope you understand my problem. [download gif file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27z5ehtylv8nzpy/excelmonth4.gif?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

**Knowns:**
List A & C, programatically, has only 13 values each.
The linked file does not match this code.  For example, `listA` is in column A not J1:J13.

Also, your code never includes `listE` in the calculation.

**Equivalent Statements:**

```
(myV - listA[i][0] - listC[j][0] == 0)
(myV - (listA[i][0] + list[j][0]) == 0)
(myV == listA[i][0] + listC[j][0])
```

One thing to note is that `myV` is a number, while `listA[i]` and `listC[j]` is an `object`.  I think this comparison is valid as long as you use "==" and not "===", which compares the "type" as well.

Maybe this is what you are after...

```
function matchCal() {    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var listA = ss.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String);
  var listC = ss.getRange("C:C").getValues().filter(String);
  var listE = ss.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String);
  var myV = 5004; //my value

  // NOTE:  Max(listA) + Max(ListC) + Max(listE) = 5040
  //        and condition is never true

  for(var i=0; i<listA.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<listC.length; j++){
      for(var k=0; k<listE.length; k++){    

        if(listA[i][0] + listC[j][0] + listE[k][0]==myV ){
          Logger.log(i+" : "+j+" : "+k);
          ss.getRange(i+1,1).setBackground("#FFFF00"); //j+1 because the row is never 0
          ss.getRange(j+1,3).setBackground("#FFFF00");
          ss.getRange(k+1,5).setBackground("#FFFF00");  
          Logger.log("Success!");
        }
      }            
    }
  }
}
```